# SSIS package failed to execute ssrs report from schedule job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs-2008-r2, job-scheduling, ssis-2008

i have a problem with ssis.
when I run it manually, the process runs smoothly and its reports are formed.
but when I run it with a schedule job in the sql server, the job is successful but the report is not formed.
in the task script settings (task to generate ssrs) I have set to save the credential : 
Try
            loRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
            loRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            loRequest.Timeout = 600000

From tutorial here : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3475/execute-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-from-integration-services-package/
(Thanks mssqltips for your great tutorial)

Comment: You need to take a basic step: look in the SSIS logs and find the error, then edit your question and add it.

Comment: Why are you executing SSRS from SSIS instead of a subscription?